# Trying to grab the created_at date via a controller in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my **pages_controller.rb**:

```
def home
   @date = Lesson.find(params[:created_at])
end
```

At this point I'm just trying to pull the date to try and visualize before I manipulate anything but when I try to call that `@date` instance variable in `home.html.erb`

The error I'm getting is `Couldn't find Lesson without an ID` but I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to such problems - use scopes

in your lesson model add:

```
scope :by_date, order("created_at DESC")
```

there's also **default_scope**

Answer (score 0):

There are several helpers wich include easy queries and return an array wich holds the Lesson records ordered by created_at datetime.

In your index action you might want to use:

```
@date = Lesson.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

when you are in your index template you might want to list them using the each sytnax and therefor route them to their show page in wich you have access to their properties.

also a Model scope would be the "cleanest" solution

just remember to hold skinny controllers and fat models

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

`find` only accepts an id. You're trying to give it a DateTime. Perhaps this is what you want?

```
@date = Lesson.find( params[:id] ).
               select( :created_at ).
               created_at
```